# Convert the image in a PictureBox into a bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

I have used the following code to convert the image in a PictureBox into a Bitmap:

```
bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image;
```

But I am getting the result as `bmp = null`. Can anyone tell me how I do this?

Comment: That can only happen when the Image property is null.  Assign the property first.

Comment: if the Image would not have been null, I guess you would have gotten an exception. an Image object can't be casted to a Bitmap, if the image is not directly a bitmap.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> As per my understanding your have not assigned PictureBox's Image
> property, so that it is returning null on type cast.
>
> PictureBox property automatically convert the Image format and if you see the tooltip on Image property, it will Show System.Drawing.Bitmap.  Check your image
> property is correctly assigned.

*Check this, it is working at my side.*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
}

private void TestForm12_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\url.gif");
}
```

/// *Using BitMap Class*

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
```

*You can  directly cast `pictureBox2.Image` to Bitmap as you are doing  and also using the Bitmap class to convert to Bitmap class object.*

**Ref:** [Bitmap Constructor (Image)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx).

> You can find more options here with the [Bitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)

Comment: You should never use `Image.FromFile(path)`. It is a simple wrapper around the `New Bitmap(path)` constructor which has no extra advantages at all but loses the more specific `Bitmap` type in the process. So just use the `New Bitmap(path)` constructor instead. Using `new Bitmap(image)` on the result is also not advised since it converts the image to 32bpp ARGB, which might not be desired if you're working specific image types you want to preserve on later saves or manipulations (like 24bpp RGB, or indexed images with palettes).

Answer (score 7):

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx

Comment: Hi Tilak ,  I just applied the code but it gives me an error as "Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object"

Comment: have you checked pictureBox2.Image for null

Answer (score 3):

I think you looking for this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image)
```